# Algorithm of resource allocation with disjoint condition

Tags: algorithm, resources, allocation

There are `n` resources to be allocated to `m` users (`n > m`). The restrictions include:
1. each resource can only be allocated to at most one user.
2. each user requires some resources or other resources to fullfill tasks.

For example, the resources are denoted by `a,b,c,d,e` and the users are `1,2,3`.
 User 1 can use one of: `(a,b), (b,c)`.
User 2 can use one of: `(b), (c), (d), (e)`.
User 3 can use one of:  `(c,d), (e,f)`.

A possible assignment may be: `(a,b)`, `(e)` and `(c,d)` for users 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

The objective is to find an allocation plan, that lets as many users as possible have enough resources.

There might be similar problems, but I find no results. Maybe it is an NPC problem, but I also find no related topic in NPC problem list.

So I want a good answer for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at an article about this problem [here](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.37.6.695?journalCode=mnsc).
This is not a trivial question, so I have no further useful ideas...

Answer (score 0):

The special case where each user has only one option is the NP-hard [set packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing), one of Karp's original 21. I would look into using an off-the-shelf constraint program solver.